# Pyton3 Pytube Finish Download Message Error

Tags: python-3.x, pytube

I wrote the code below, it works fine, but I want to print "download has started, and is continuing" when the download starts, and "download is finished" when the download is finished, but I couldn't.

```
from pytube import YouTube
yt=YouTube(input("giriş?\n"))
stream = yt.streams.get_by_itag(22)
stream.download()
```

Answer (score 1):

By placing the print statements strategically, this should work

```
from pytube import YouTube
yt=YouTube(input("giriş?\n"))
stream = yt.streams.get_by_itag(22)
print('download has started, and is continuing')
stream.download()
print('download is finished')
```

Answering from my phone, code not tested though